# Non-resolvable parent POM in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, proxy, http-proxy

I've imported a maven project in to Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0), but I have this error in the pom file. I have already the same project in another computer and it is working fine. The project is a springBoot 2.0.6.RELEASE

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for es.teatreDeGuerrila:teatreDeGuerrilaCloudApp:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE from 
 https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: 
 Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out and 
 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM
```

and I have a lot of compilation errors in the classes, like

```
The import org.springframework cannot be resolved
```

from the command line, using `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`, everything works fine.

and I already the proxy in Eclipse as Manual with the same settings I have in the file `../maven/conf/settings.xml`

```
<proxy>
      <id>httpproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.teatre.guerrila.int</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
     <proxy>
      <id>httpsproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <host>proxy.teatre.guerrila.int</host>
      <port>8443</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

[Eclipse settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54NPP.png)

Comment: You have network issues: `connect timed out and ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using an external maven and not the embedded one.
Please check that

1) *In eclispe -> preferences -> Maven -> Installations* you have checked the external maven

2) *In eclispe -> preferences -> Maven -> User Settings* pont to the settings file you mention